# Что за ошибка и как исправить в electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

Есть у меня старый проект на `electron`, который не доделан. Решил взяться за него и допилить всё что не сделал, но при запуске его получаю такое:

```
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\olegp\mini_library_2020\client_reader\node_modules\electron-prebuilt-compile\lib\main.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at forgeSpawn (C:\Users\olegp\mini_library_2020\client_reader\node_modules\@electron-forge\core\src\api\start.ts:81:26)
    at forgeSpawnWrapper (C:\Users\olegp\mini_library_2020\client_reader\node_modules\@electron-forge\core\src\api\start.ts:121:21)
    at C:\Users\olegp\mini_library_2020\client_reader\node_modules\@electron-forge\cli\src\electron-forge-start.ts:58:19 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\olegp\\mini_library_2020\\client_reader\\node_modules\\electron-prebuilt-compile\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'C:\\Users\\olegp\\mini_library_2020\\client_reader\\node_modules\\electron-prebuilt-compile'
}

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
```

Как это можно исправить?

**Дополнение**

Вижу, что нет никакого `main.js` в указанной папке. Но как мне установить и надо ли вообще это делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версии пакетов:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.54",
    "electron": "^1.3.2",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "^1.3.2"
```

Вот что ещё интересное нашёл:

```
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated constantinople@3.0.2: Please update to at least constantinople 3.1.1
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated electron-prebuilt@1.3.2: electron-prebuilt has been renamed to electron. For more details, see http://electron.atom.io/blog/2016/08/16/npm-install-electron
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
```

Это происходит при запуске `npm install`. Получается, что часть модулей просто не установилась корректно... Как можно поправить?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Использовал `npm update` и всё заработало